# Separating a list into 4 item lists in python?

Tags: python, list, shellcode

I'm working on a python script to generate shell code for a programming class. The program will take unformatted shell code "aabbccdd", break it up into 2 character list items, and insert \x to each byte. The problem is that it's on a little endian processor, so I need reverse the list items in 4 item chunks. I was thinking the easiest way to do this would be to join the list into a string and use string.split with "\x" as the argument, but I can't figure out how to do only 4 at a time/put then in separate lists so I can use list.reverse on each list, join them together and then back to a string for printing. My approach seems clunky and I can't figure out how to get it to work, would love some help from one of you smart folks!

Edit - I figured it out. I thought i was encoding my shellcode incorrectly, when in reality I had two problems - NX Byte was turned on, and I was filling the SFP with the last part of my shellcode instead of using junk bytes to fill it. This made my shellcode terminate before it had fully executed, as the SFP is not executable. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: put some code you already have for a start.

Comment: I'm not sure about your intention... but try something like `r'\x'.join(reversed(your_string[::2]))`

Comment: @SaulloCastro: that'd only put `\x` in between.

Comment: I don't want to spoil your exercise so I won't give you a concrete answer. I'll just give general advise for solving programming problems: Start with the simplest, most straightforward method you can think of. Use basic flow control and data structures to get the job done. After you've got it working, think how you could simplify your solution.

Comment: What should your result look like for this example?

Comment: return_address=[return_address[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(return_address), n)]

return_address.reverse()

return_address = ["\\x{0}".format(elem) for elem in return_address]

return_address = "".join(return_address)

Comment: I can't figure out how to format that on here my first post here. So, the class I'm taking doesn't want me to write this program, it wants me to exploit a a buffer overflow. I just got tired of writing \x in front of everything, and I saw a need, so I tried to write a program.

The output is kindof unreadable, as it goes to perl for printing and becomes raw binary data. But here's what it should look like before that: Input=31c031db31c931d2 output=\xdb\x31\xc0\x31\xd2\x31\xc9\x31.

Answer (score 2):

That's already built-in (Python 2):

```
>>> s = "aabbccdd"
>>> s.decode("hex")
'\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd'
```

I don't understand yet what you mean exactly by "reversing the list items in 4 item chunks".

Comment: I seriously searched for hours and couldn't find that. I just needed to reverse them for little-endian/loading onto the stack. But, I just realized the stack is FILO, not little endian so I can just reverse the whole thing instead of reversing each individual word.